# Online Flowchart Diagram Tool (run from private wiki)

Tags: wiki, diagram, flowchart

Is there some flowchart diagram tool that would (or could be made to) integrate with a self-hosted wiki?

Requirements:

- basic functionality (e.g., drawing some boxes and some arrows)
- would strongly prefer it to be visual (i.e., not written out in text that then gets converted)
- allows for dynamic editing
- it is important that the tool can be integrated into the wiki (e.g., as an extra panel somewhere)
- can be run from a personal server
- free

I've looked around at other threads here concerning a diagram tool, but they are either desktop applications, online ones which reside on third-party servers, or cost money.

[Edit] Thanks for the responses, but I would like them to be dynamically editable (I've added this to the requirements).  What I mean is that I would like to integrate (or run it from a private server) some online collaborative diagramming tool.  While I could create a JPG of something made in Graphviz and upload it, this is not easily editable.  I would have to upload the source file somewhere, which someone would have to download and edit, then upload the new JPG.

Comment: Nice question.  I'm looking for something similar.  Not for pure flow charts, but to describe business processes in a Wiki.

Answer (score 4):

Graphviz dot diagrams can be embedded in some wikis.  Unfortunately for your requirements, it's text that gets converted.  It's fairly simple to learn and use though.

http://www.graphviz.org/

EDIT: It's free / open source.

Comment: Worth noting that this is now available as a [mediawiki extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GraphViz).

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for something similar - collaborative flowcharts in a wiki. The most interesting so far is this Mediawiki extension: http://www.flowchartwiki.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

[Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/xwiki) for [XWiki](http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) is the closest thing I've seen.  It's more of a previsualization tool however for application mockups, though I'm not sure if this is the kind of tool you're looking for.

It is free if you [qualify](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/xwiki#nonprofit) under their licensing.

Another option would be using [Mediawiki with the Dia](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Dia) extension.

Answer (score 1):

I like using the [svgedit](http://github.com/Harvie/DokuWiki-Plugin-SVGEdit) plugin in dokuwiki for quick diagramming on the run. It produces standard SVG text files and has an always up to the date javascript wysiwyg editor. And, I submitted a bug/feature request on github and the requested functionality was added post haste.

Edit: FOSS!

Answer (score 1):

i understand this question is old enough. but you could try [Origramy](http://origramy.com/). it's a Flash-based visual tool. and XML as the result can be get from the component. alas integration to wiki must be made separately

Comment: That isn't quite what I'm looking for.  I want to be able to edit it directly from within the wiki.  This product is more about creating a "static" diagram for a presentation, website, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the technology you have on your server, but [Open Diagram](http://opendiagram.codeplex.com) can create a jpg image file on the server which can then be referenced as a normal image in your wiki. Its open source.

Answer (score 0):

I've enjoyed the simplicity of [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/) for a while as a desktop app. Don't let the name fool you! There is more than just UML - it has a lot of basic charting elements in it. It's not pretty, and it can be awkward sometimes, but it works. Has basic visual items in a template/toolbox that you double-click on to reproduce on your canvas. You can then move it about, resize it, or edit the item and modify it via text.

There isn't an existing online integration method (that I've seen), but being that it's good old fashioned java, you might be able to make it happen.

It's free and distributed under the GNU General Public Licence.

Answer (score -1):

honestly i think you are going to have to use Java and code an applet. there are wondrous advancements in javascript libraries (AJAX, JQuery) that also might assist in this...

cheers my friend.